# running html5 in an android emulator

Tags: android, html, emulation

I've just started developing an html5 game using VS Code.  I see it being mainly used from pcs/laptops and have managed to set up the Chrome debugger so I can debug the webpage in chrome.

However I'd like to be able to debug it using an android emulator too, to check the screens look right, etc.  I have Android Studio installed, and an emulator that works, but I can't find any VS Code debugger extensions that will launch the webpage in the browser of the emulator.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the mobile device view in the developer tools of any current browser?

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, and so easy !  I spent a good couple of hours looking for a far more complicated solution.  Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

**This method is tested both on emulator and actual physical device.**

Goto Chrome. Then goto `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

**Physical Device:**

Then you can connect your phone to pc and turn on `USB Debugging` on your phone. Accept the debugging message on your phone. Then you get access to all chromium based apps like Chrome, Brave or other Hybrid apps developed using Cordova etc.

**Emulator:**

Close all emulators running. Start Android Studio. Start the emulator. Goto Android Studio logcat and check if emulated is alive. Then goto `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

**If emulator ADB authentication fails in chrome. Goto AVD manager and wipe data of virtual device.(Only Emulator)**

[image: Inspect Devices]